# Threat Risk Assessment

Tags: security, risk-analysis, threat-model, nist

I have to do a Threat Risk Assessment for one of my customers. Can anyone please share some template or provide some pointers as to what all needs to be checked or audited for Threat Risk Assessment. Can be applicable to cloud as well as On-Prem both

Answer (score 0):

One interesting resource I think: https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/Legacy/SP/nistspecialpublication800-30r1.pdf.
The interesting part is in the appendix: you have some table and questions used for the evaluation.
I do not know any prebuilt template or dashboard except in paid risk assessment software.